# I need to change a Robot variable by command line using another variable

Tags: python, robotframework

So I've looked into it a lot so I think maybe I'm thinking of a complex solution to a simple problem.
I have a test in Robot that uses a variable in a python dictionary.

The robot file:

```
*** Settings ***
Variables       Data.py

*** Variables ***
${check}=       TEST.abc

*** Test Cases ***
Test                          
    Do the test         ${check}
```

The python dictionary:

```
DICT__TEST = {"abc": "123", "def":"456"}
```

In this case above I would like to, for instance, pass the variable `"def"` as a parameter in the command line to replace the variable `${check}`.
I saw that there is the `--variable` but it just changes the Robot's variable by a string, and not by another variable.
The dictionary is already working normally with Robot, as I don't have much experience I might be thinking of a very difficult way to solve something simple. I accept other suggestions, but basically I have a very big string that I need to pass through the command line to change my variable in Robot.

Comment: You could supply "def" with --variable command line and use it as a key for Get From Dictionary in Suite Setup

Comment: would you have an example of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you have key-value pairs in a dictionary and you want to get save value to a variable. And you want to supply key from the command line.

You can run `robot -v dictkey:def mytest.robot` and it will use variable

```
*** Settings ***
Library         Collections
Suite Setup     SetDict

*** Variables ***
${dictkey}    abc

*** Keywords ***
SetDict
    ${sample_dict}=     Create Dictionary    abc  123   def   456
    Set Suite Variable  ${sample_dict}

*** Test Cases ***
Test
    ${value}=         Get From Dictionary    ${sample_dict}   ${dictkey}
    Log To Console    ${value}
```